# Testing a Grafana dashboard with client error: 407

Tags: proxy, alert, telegram, prometheus, grafana

I'm using Grafana with Prometheus as DataSource. Those environments are behind a proxy, the communication was already open and I can test Telegram notification with success, but testing an alert in a dashboard I get the following error:

```
"tsdb.HandleRequest() error client_error: client error: 407"
```

Any ideia why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 407 status code = Proxy Authentication Required, so it looks like your proxy doesn't like that request for some reason. I guess you can check proxy logs to see more details.